# Spark+Scala: Merging multiple dataframes in an efficient way

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I am processing thousands of NetCDF files to create a master dataframe on which further computations are done. Earlier, I was able to do this quite fast using `SciSpark` with Spark 2.x, but it does not seem to work any longer with Spark 3.x. So I have now used the generic `NetCDF-java` [reader](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/). I had to rework the implementation and I want to improve on the performance as well, if possible.

In the earlier version, through `SciSpark`, I was able to create the master dataframe in a way that required too much space as it loaded into memory all the content from all the input files. Now I wrote a function that is more efficient as it creates a dataframe for each file and retains only the minimal content instead of all its data. Such file-based dataframes are merged to form the master dataframe. However, here I face a problem as the process keeps crashing, and also seems to utilize much less CPU when it runs as well. The essential code that is of concern here is:

```
def fileListToDataframe(flist: String): DataFrame = {
    val ipFiles = scala.io.Source.fromFile(flist).mkString.split("\n")

    val dataFrames = ipFiles.par.map {x => fileToDF(x)}  // frac. of data is stored per file
    val mergedDataFrame = dataFrames.par.reduce(_ union _)

    return mergedDataFrame
}
```

Sample error:

```
ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 60 on 122.xx.yy.zz: Command exited with code 0
INFO task 15.0 in stage 7718.0 (TID 132079) failed because while it was being computed, its executor exited for a reason unrelated to the task. Not counting this failure towards the maximum number of failures for the task.
WARN Dispatcher: Message RequestMessage(server:33867, NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@server:33867), ReviveOffers) dropped due to sparkEnv is stopped. Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.
```

The above code worked for 500 files, but when 10K files are given as input, the process seems just not to complete. The master dataframe requires only a few GB of RAM (while the system has 2TiB). Is there a way to make the above computation better?

Comment: can you please tell me what are you going to do once you merge DataFrame's ?

Comment: This is just preprocessing as any calculations done are on the master dataframe.

Comment: Can you do same calculations in child DataFrame & then aggregate at master DataFrame, in this way your final DataFrame has to deal with less number of data & it can fit into memory?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work as filtering has to be done based on statistics from the whole dataframe. The same was accomplished with `SciSpark`, so it should be possible.

Comment: Can you please share code ?

Comment: There many factors here. Since the message indicates that failure happened on the executor, you can start by adjusting executor's memory and CPU resources accordingly i.e increase the available executor memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally solve the problem by doing the following:

1. Make a dataframe with file names in a column
2. Convert to a dataset using case class with a method that includes the file reading.

This enabled me to get Spark-based solution; however number of executors also affect the performance. Curiously, using 1 executor with all available cores thrown in gave almost 100% CPU usage (though a little slower than optimum number of executors).